# Can't save model with href tag in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, mezzanine, django-tinymce

I am using `mezzanine` cms which uses `django-tinymce` to provide `RichTextField`, I put the link like this using both link and html editor:

`<p><a href=""www.faceook.com">Facebook</a></p>`

When I save it, it automatically turns into:

`<p><a>Facebook</a></p>`

`href` is gone just like that. what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span><a href="foo" target="_blank" style="yourstyle">Facebook</a></span>
```